# How to make InkScape SVG file fill browser window and be interactive?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, inkscape

I have an SVG graphic, drawn up in InkScape which has some javascript interactivity: http://docs.shapeoko.com/content/tPictures/25203-02.svg

I need to somehow open it into a new browser window/tab and have it fill the screen and have the javascript interactivity still work.

This file http://docs.shapeoko.com/25203-02.html fills the screen using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
  <title>Project ShapeOko diagram 25203-02</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { background:#fff; margin:0 }
  </style>
</head><body><img src="content/tPictures/25203-02-js.svg" alt="V-Wheel Assembly" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></img></body></html>
```

but isn't interactive.

This file http://docs.shapeoko.com/25203-02-test.html doesn't fill the screen

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
  <title>Project ShapeOko diagram 25203-02</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { background:#fff; margin:0 }
    </style>
</head><body><object type="image/svg+xml" data="content/tPictures/25203-02.svg" id="25203-02" alt="V-Wheel Assembly" width="100%" height="100%" class="svg-content">    </object></body></html>
```

but is interactive (you can click on the part #s to get the matching part image(s) to highlight).

How can I get both filling the window and the diagram being interactive?

I've tried everything I could find, but apparently don't understand the contents of the search results --- please break it down simply, or provide a compleat solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit svg source like this.

- append viewBox attribute same as svg's size.
- replace width and height attribute to 100%

---

```
<svg
   ---
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 800 400"
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, and is even persistent if one edits the SVG in Inkscape. Did I miss a way to set that in the interface?

Comment: Unfortunately, when testing further, things didn't work so well: 

 - PC / Firefox --- works
 - PC / Chrome --- works
 - PC / Internet Explorer --- file renders too small on the page, clicking to enlarge works.
 - iPad / Safari --- file renders okay in page and allows zooming, opening the .svg in it's own tab doesn't work (blank screen)
 - iPad / Chrome --- works (once updated to current version)
 - Mac / Firefox --- works
 - Mac / Safari --- image is distorted on web page, clicking to enlarge works